# Build a SQL query "self-joining"

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm working on a database, with a table named stop_times structed as :

```
+-------+-------------------+---------+----------+----------+
| st_id | trip_id           | stop_id | time     | stop_seq |
+-------+-------------------+---------+----------+----------+
|     1 | 10000872820081804 |   22789 | 17:33:00 |        1 |
|     2 | 10000872820081804 |   22791 | 17:39:00 |        2 |
|     3 | 10000872820081804 |   22793 | 17:41:00 |        3 |
|     4 | 10000872820081805 |   22794 | 17:33:00 |        1 |
|     5 | 10000872820081805 |   22792 | 17:35:00 |        2 |
| [...] |       [...]       |  [...]  |   [...]  |   [...]  |
+-------+-------------------+---------+----------+----------+
```

A `stop_id` can be associated with multiples `trip_id`, for instance :

```
+-------+------------------+---------+----------+----------+
| st_id | trip_id          | stop_id | time     | stop_seq |
+-------+------------------+---------+----------+----------+
| 91447 | 1017694581039141 |    1778 | 17:44:00 |       15 |
| 91599 | 1017694590917762 |    1778 | 22:40:00 |       20 |
| 91717 | 1017694610917762 |    1778 | 22:40:00 |       20 |
| 91773 | 1017694610968899 |    1778 | 16:48:00 |       15 |
| 91909 | 1017694640917762 |    1778 | 22:40:00 |       20 |
| [...] |       [...]      |   [...] |   [...]  |   [...]  |
+-------+------------------+---------+----------+----------+
```

Given a `stop_id` A, I need to find its neighbours (of `stop_id` B), a neighbour being defined as :

- A and B have a common `trip_id` (e.g. the entries 1, 2 and 3 comply with this condition)
- `stop_seq` of B must be the smallest upper-bound of A `stop_seq` of A (typically *(+1)*)

For instance, here *22789* and *22791* are neighboors they share a `trip_id` (for instance, *10000872820081804*, but they actually share a lot of other `trip_id`s) and that `stop_seq` of *22789* is 1, and `stop_seq` of *22791* is 2 (and 2 = min({2, 3}) where {2, 3} = {stop_seq s.t. trip_id = 10000872820081804 and stop_seq > 1} **<--** the upper_bounds set of `stop_seq` of `22789`)

Finally, I need to get the time between both stops, which is the substraction of both times, but I guess I could manage this (even I don't really know how to substract times in SQL, I guess you can achieve that with some SQL functions..)

And something quite more difficult : From the neighbours, there will be many duplicate (because a lot of trips will have these 2 stops as neighbours) so I need to find the closest to a given time (i.e. the substraction of the stop time minus the given time is minimal and positive)

---

For instance if `SELECT * FROM stop_times WHERE stop_id = 2045` returns this :

```
+-------+------------------+---------+----------+----------+
| st_id | trip_id          | stop_id | time     | stop_seq |
+-------+------------------+---------+----------+----------+
| 91421 | 1017694581039138 |    2045 | 12:01:00 |       21 |
| 91449 | 1017694581039141 |    2045 | 17:48:00 |       17 |
| 91511 | 1017694590917740 |    2045 | 10:13:00 |       21 |
| 91543 | 1017694590917746 |    2045 | 12:43:00 |       21 |
| 91601 | 1017694590917762 |    2045 | 22:43:00 |       22 |
+-------+------------------+---------+----------+----------+
```

(I did a `LIMIT 5` but let's assume it returns only that). Then, I know (by browsing the database) that :

- For the trip *1017694581039138* the next stop (of `stop_seq` = 22 here, 22 being the smallest number > than 21, the stop_seq  of *2045* on the trip) is *1809* and the time of travel is 5min (12:06 - 12:01 where 12:06 is the time in the row of *1809*).
- For the trip *1017694581039141* the next stop (of `stop_seq` = 18) is *1809* and the time of travel is 1min.
- etc..

Let's say I give the time 12:00, and that there is another trip that goes to *1809* then (let's say at 14:00), I want the query to display only the one at 12:01 (because it's the closest to the time I gave).

For instance, both *1017694590917740* and *1017694590917746* also lead to *1809* here, however *1017694590917740* is already past if I give 12:00 as time, and *1017694590917746* is not as close from 12:00 as *1017694581039138* is (12:01 vs 12:40), so the only trip to *1809* I want the query to return is *1017694581039138*.

(Also, doing that for every stop would be possible but it would imply giving a list of trips associated to a time leading to each distinct neighbour of each node, as :

```
Node 1
+--- Neighbour 1
      +--- Time 
      +--- Other time
      +--- etc.
+--- Neighbour 2
      +--- etc.
Node 2
+--- etc.
etc.
```

But this would need a sort-of json-like structure, which I dont really know how to achieve in SQL)

---

How can I do that ?

(I've tried with subqueries and joining but I'm a bit uncomfortable with SQL and it quickly become complex, and after a short while trying to work this out I feel like I'd need **foreach** or **for** statements, **if**s and others stuffs)

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus just on the *next* stop, rather then the *prev* stop.

Given your constraints, you can find the *next* stop on each trip using:

```
select st.*,
       (select st2.st_id
        from stop_times st2
        where st2.trip_id = st.trip_id and st2.stop_seq > st.stop_seq
        order by st2.stop_seq
        limit 1
       ) as next_st_id
from stop_times st;
```

We can join back to the table to get information about the next stop, and use aggregation to get the minimum time (and a trick to get other information as well):

```
select st.stop_id, stn.stop_id as next_stop_id,
       min(stn.time) as min_time,
       timestampdiff(second, min(stn.time), st.time) as seconds_diff,
       substring_index(group_concat(stn.st_id order by stn.time), ',', 1) as next_st_id,
       substring_index(group_concat(stn.trip_id order by stn.time), ',', 1) as next_trip_id     
from (select st.*,
             (select st2.st_id
              from stop_times st2
              where st2.trip_id = st.trip_id and st2.stop_seq > st.stop_seq
              order by st2.stop_seq
              limit 1
             ) as next_st_id
      from stop_times st
     ) st join
     stop_times stn
     on stn.st_id = st.next_st_id
group by st.stop_id, stn.stop_id ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But  `select st2.st_id
        from stop_times st2
        where st2.trip_id = st.trip_id
        order by st2.stop_seq
        limit 1` will return the first stop of the trip, and not the first 'upper-bound' (i.e. the next stop on the trip). I don't really undertand the query tho :?